# Samsung Galaxy S3 camera light keeps flashing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera-flash

Ever since I updated the software on my Galaxy S3 the camera light flashes randomly all day, it also flashes when my alarm goes off.

I cannot find anywhere in my settings how to disable this annoying light. My flash notification is not checked off. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

S3 users have reported similar issue while receiving calls and alarm going off at AndroidCentral forums [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii/336303-t-galaxy-siii-4-3-update-likes-issues.html#post3258552).

The solution posted there is to go to `Settings > My Device > Accessibility > Hearing > Flash Notification`

Un-check Flash Notification.

Even if the flash notification box is not checked, check it once and un-check it again. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Was annoying, but has stopped, by doing the following:

Go to: Settings > My Device > Accessibility> Hearing> Flash notification

Select flash, close out, return and deselect flash.

Working properly now!

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon could be due to some rogue app that is using the permissions of the camera to take pictures or activating flashlight without your intervention.

Check with some app like [F-Secure App Permissions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsecure.app.permissions.privacy), applying the advanced filter **CAMERA**, **FLASHLIGHT** (applying **OR** operator as shown in the screenshots).

In the resulting list, look for any suspicious app (mainly a game or another app that should not be using those permissions) and uninstall it (you can uninstall apps directly from **F-Secure App Permissions** by long-tapping its name in the list and tapping **Yes** in the confirmation message).

[image: Select Advanced filter] [image: Applying filter "CAMERA OR FLASHLIGHT"] [image: List of filtered apps]

Answer (score 0):

I found it was a flashlight app I had downloaded. It had permissions to override various functions. After uninstalling the app, the flashing is gone!